# Pdf file url's are not working in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, pdf, cordova, childbrowser

Am using

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no')
```

to open external web page, wherein that web page contains pdf file links. The problem am facing is these pdf links are not working within that browser.

If I use

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes')
```

or

```
window.open(url, '_blank')
```

is working as expected. In this scenario everything is working fine.

But since my requirement is to hide the address bar, am giving `location=no` as argument to `window.open()`. Here pdf links are not working inside web page which is opened via

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no')
```

How can I resolve this issue? Please give suggestions.

Comment: you can't open pdf in android, Try to use. google doc

Comment: Please view this question that will help u . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462707/if-link-is-http-google-com-it-worked-but-if-i-change-link-to-my-pdf-url-i/38463242#38463242

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
   $(".drawListItem").on("click",function(){

           var url = 'https://www.google.co.in';
           window.open("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+url,"_blank","location=yes");

   });
```